# No media on Usb drive

Tags: partitioning, usb, mount

I was copying Garuda Linux iso (arch based linux distro) using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, on my 64Gb pen-drive and the copying stopped at 99%. I tried canceling the operation and copy pasted again, overriding the left over part from previous attempt, operation didn't completed and my pendrive was ejected automatically,i removed the drive and inserted it again and now it shows "No Media" and isn't recognised by ubuntu as well as windows in their respective file managers. It shows as "NAND Drive" in disks in ubuntu and storage management in windows. How can i fix it ? ( it doesn't matter if data on the drive is lost in the process, i need the drive functional again. )

Comment: I have had several flash drives do that and spent hours trying to fix them without success. Perhaps the vendor will honor the warranty. I have had Lexar and Kingston flash  drives fail, who made yours?

Comment: HP, purchased it more than a year ago. so hard luck on warranty as well

Comment: Flash drives are becoming less reliable, I am still using a 13 year old, 4GB, Kingston USB2 flash drive every day. The last Kingston I bought lasted two weeks. I think all of my dead flash drives were bought from Amazon.

Comment: Try to find the programmer app of your USB drive controller chipset. In my case, using "https://www.usbdev.ru/files/firstchip/fc1179mptools/" solved the problem.

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) and if you are lucky, find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, use this command to find your drive:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

It will show you the disks that are on your system. Try to find your flash drive. It can be named /dev/sdc, for example.

Now try formatting the device. You can do that using Gparted (GUI) or commands like:

```
sudo umount *your/device*

sudo mkfs -t FAT32 *your/device*
```

See if it fixes.

Further, I recommend using Balena Etcher to make a bootable drive, if that was what you were trying to do.

Comment: it isn't shown when i used 'sudo fdisk -l' , it only lists my internal hdd